# Any formulæ for products of consecutive cyclotomic polynomials?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, cyclotomic-polynomials

I am interested in any information about coefficients of the polynomials $\Psi_n(x):=\prod_{k=1}^n\Phi_k(x)$, where $\Phi_k$ are the [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

I realize of course that this is a complicated object and presumably very little is known about it, but even that little I don't know.

Practically the only thing I know is the degree - it is $D(n):=\sum_{k=1}^n\varphi(k)$, where $\varphi(k)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). This is easy to show anyway, the degree coincides with the number of elements in the $n$th [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence), as the polynomial has all primitive roots of 1 up to $n$ as its simple roots.

To pose some concrete (sub)question - it seems that one has
$$
\Psi_n(e^{it})=2ie^{\frac{D(n)}2it}\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{D(n)}2}c_n\left(k\right)\sin(kt)
$$
where, for each $n$, $c_n\left(k\right)$, $k=1,...,\frac{D(n)}2$ is a [unimodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality#Unimodal_function) sequence of natural numbers - for example,

3. $2ie^{2it}(\sin(t)+\sin(2t))$
4. $2ie^{3it}(\sin(t)+\sin(2t)+\sin(3t))$
5. $2ie^{5it}(2\sin(t)+3\sin(2t)+3\sin(3t)+2\sin(4t)+\sin(5t))$
6. $2ie^{6it}(\sin(t)+2\sin(2t)+2\sin(3t)+2\sin(4t)+\sin(5t)+\sin(6t))$
7. $2ie^{9it}(4\sin(t)+7\sin(2t)+9\sin(3t)+9\sin(4t)+8\sin(5t)+6\sin(6t)+4\sin(7t)$ $+2\sin(8t)+\sin(9t))$
8. $2ie^{11it}(5\sin(t)+9\sin(2t)+12\sin(3t)+13\sin(4t)+13\sin(5t)+11\sin(6t)+9\sin(7t)+6\sin(8t)+4\sin(9t)+2\sin(10t)+\sin(11t))$

Is there a chance to prove this unimodality, or just positivity, or any arithmetic properties of these coefficients? Like, what is $c_n\left(1\right)$? Or, it is more or less clear that the highest coefficient $c_n\left(\frac{D(n)}2\right)$ is 1; but what is the previous one, $c_n\left(\frac{D(n)}2-1\right)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I will use $a_n(k)$ to denote
$$\Psi_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{D(n)}a_n(k)x^k$$

First, let us give the property that for some
$$P(x) = a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$$
such that the coefficients obey $a_k = -a_{n-k}$ a name. We will call it 'odd symmetry'.

We want to prove that the coefficients of $\Psi_n(x)$ are odd symmetric. To prove this we use the identity
$$\Phi_n(x) = x^{\phi(n)}\Phi_n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
for $n>1$, as for $n=1$ we have
$$\Phi_1(x) = -x\Phi_1\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
and hence
$$\Phi_1(x)\prod_{k=2}^n\Phi_k(x) = \left(-x\Phi_1\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\prod_{k=2}^nx^{\phi(k)}\Phi_k\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\Phi_k(x) = -x^{D(n)}\prod_{k=1}^n\Phi_k\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$\Psi_n(x) = -x^{D(n)}\Psi_n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
This proves that the coefficients are odd symmetric.

So we have just proven that

$$a_n(k) = -a_n\left(D(n)-k\right)$$

You can let $x=e^{it}$ and use the same algebraic manipulations you did to get
$$\Psi_n(e^{it}) = 2ie^{itD(n)/2}\sum_{k=1}^{D(n)/2}c_n(k)\sin(kt)$$
But instead on $-e^{itD(n)}\Psi_n\left(e^{-it}\right)$, and you will see that
$$-e^{itD(n)}\Psi_n\left(e^{-it}\right) = \Psi_n(e^{it})= 2ie^{itD(n)/2}\sum_{k=1}^{D(n)/2}a_n\left(\frac{D(n)}{2}+k\right)\sin(kt)$$
and hence
$$c_n(k) = a_n\left(\frac{D(n)}{2}+k\right)$$

Now we will prove that $c_n(k)$ is not unimodular by giving a counter-example. Using [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), the roots of $\Psi_n(x)$ (denoted $\zeta$), and the fact that $\Phi_n(x)$ is a monic polynomial and hence $a_n(D(n)) = -a_n(0) = 1$, we get that

$$\zeta_1+\zeta_2+\ldots+\zeta_{D(n)} = -a_n(D(n)-1) = a_n(1)$$
$$ = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{1\leq m\leq k, \gcd(m,k)=1}\mu(m) = \sum_{k=1}^n\mu(k) = M(n)$$
where we used an identity of the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function#Properties) and where $M(n)$ denotes the [Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function). The first value for which $M(n)$ for $n>2$ is zero or greater in absolute value is $M(39)$, and so we have then that $c_{39}(k)$ is not a unimodal sequence as it would look like $\{37634362806, \ldots, 3, 0, 1,\ldots\}$.

Since you mentioned Farey sequences, you can read the connection between Farey sequences, $M(n)$ and $D(n)$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function#As_a_sum_over_Farey_sequences) (note that $D(n)$ is denoted as $\Phi(n)$ in the article).

So we have proven that $c_n(k)$ is not always unimodal

That $\Psi_n(x)$ is odd symmetric

That the 'highest coefficient' $c_n(\frac{D(n)}{2}) = 1$ (using the fact that we are taking the product of monic polynomials)

and that  $c_n(\frac{D(n)}{2}-1) = M(n)$

Hope this helps!

Comment: Minor correction - $c_{39}$ only violates unimodality at $k=236$, not near $1$. Namely, $c_{39}(1)=37634362806$, $c_{39}(2)=75194598946$, $c_{39}(3)=112606835926$, ..., $c_{39}(38)=887784424515$, $c_{39}(39)=888113675962$, $c_{39}(40)=887253024823$, ..., $c_{39}(233)=8$, $c_{39}(234)=3$, $c_{39}(235)=3$, $c_{39}(236)=0$, $c_{39}(237)=1$, and $c_{39}(237+k)=0$ for $k>0$

Comment: Yes, you are correct! And I'll edit out the first part of the sequence... This follows from the fact that $c_n(k) = a_n\left(\frac{D(n)}{2}+k\right)$, and that $D(39)/2 = 237$. In the last part of the answer I state that we have proven that
$$c_n\left(\frac{D(n)}{2}-1\right) = M(n)$$
and since $D(39)/2 = 237$
$$c_n\left(237-1\right)$$ is where unimodality is violated. Thanks for pointing that out